# how to convert IFC 3D file to GLTF using Xbim in .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working with **Xbim** libraries to convert IFC file into GLTF file. I am successfully achieved the same in .net framework 4.7.2 but when I am trying to execute in .net core 3.0 I am facing error.

[Exeception for same library in .net core 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNbV7.png)

Please assist me with the same weather Xbim.Gltf.IO libraries are available for .net core 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Xbim only works with the .net framework. However, there is a compatibility NuGet package by Microsoft to use .net dependant library with .net core. See here: [Microsoft compatibility package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility)

However, this package only work if you’re using Windows; your .net core project cannot run on linux anymore.